# How to manage jenkins jobs that needs to run against several branches?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Let's say that you have 5 different jenkins jobs that are executed (triggered) on different conditions but now you want to extend the usage over the other branches.

Just duplicating the jobs would create a real maintenance mess, as the number of branches is big and under permanent change but you still want to be able to edit the jobs templates.

The only thing different between the jobs are the source control branches against you run them.

So, it does make sense to run them as different jobs but you still want to be able to reconfigure the jobs in a single place.

Comment: Sorin, do you plan to run those jobs (for the different streams) in parallel or sequentially? Do you wish to have all streams compiled at the same time, or each will have its own pace?

Answer (score 1):

For builds that do not need to be triggered by SCM changes the easiest is to use a multi-configuration (matrix) build with *BRANCH* axis that runs over your branch names.

For builds that are triggered by SCM changes add *BRANCH* parameter and write a post-commit hook that will trigger the build(s) with *BRANCH* instantiated appropriately. Alternatively, write short trigger jobs - one per branch - that would poll SCM and call your main job with the appropriate *BRANCH* parameter. Trigger jobs should be identical except for the *BRANCH* parameter that is set to a branch name as a default value.

The biggest drawback is that you **can't instantly distinguish among branches that fail and those that don't**, but it's a small price to pay.

Chances are that sooner or later you'll need to differentiate among branches. If the differences are relatively minor you can use [Run Condition Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Run+Condition+Plugin).

Comment: Note that using a matrix this way will cause all builds to run for all streams whenever a build is triggered.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. Currently I think that it would be essential to be able to distinguish between branches. Probably I will have to look for creating a special job that creates/removes jobs for each branch based on a template. Also, I do not see the use for the Condition Plugin, I think I could just use bash scripting to implement the same without the plugin, or I got it wrong?